# jQuery: why isn't this alert firing?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

broken Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sTzCS/52/

If you go to the fiddle, you should be able to drag and drop the teams in the list into a new order. You can also input a value for the amount of points you think each team will get over the season. The jQuery reads the sort order after you finish rearranging them, and it also tries to get the input value for each team.

The alert (that I created for testing purposes) in the fiddle is supposed to show the team that you put in first position and the amount of points you expected them to get. However, the alert's not firing.  jLint says the code is valid. I'm using the alert to make sure that I'm actually getting the right values. Can you explain why the alert's not working?

```
<form<form id="new_entry">

<ul id="sortlist">

        <li id="Vancouver">Canucks<input type="text" name="name" id="vanpoints"></li>
        <li id="Toronto">Toronto<input type="text" name="name" id="torontopoints"></li>
        <li id="Montreal">Montreal<input type="text" name="name" id="montrealpoints"></li>
        <li id="Ottawa">Ottawa<input type="text" name="name" id="ottawapoints"></li>
        <li id="Calgary">Calgary<input type="text" name="name" id="calgarypoints"></li>
        <li id="Edmonton">Edmonton<input type="text" name="name" id="edmontonpoints"></li>
        <li id="Winnipeg">Winnipeg<input type="text" name="name" id="winnipegpoints"></li>
</ul>
<input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$("#sortlist").sortable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        result = $("#sortlist").sortable("toArray");
        var attributes;
        attributes = {
            first: { team: result[0].id, value: result[0].children()[0].val() },
       second : { team: result[1].id, value: result[1].children()[0].val() },
        third: { team: result[2].id, value: result[2].children()[0].val() },
        fourth: { team: result[3].id, value: result[3].children()[0].val() },
        fifth: { team: result[4].id, value: result[4].children()[0].val() },
        sixth: { team: result[5].id, value: result[5].children()[0].val() },
        seventh: { team: result[6].id, value: result[6].children()[0].val() }
        };

        alert(attributes.first.team + attributes.first.value);
    }
});
```

Comment: Check for errors in developers console in your browser

Comment: There must be syntax error or null value error ,before the alert statement

Comment: @Ohgodwhy why is that? I clearly see that `value` is defined.

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov console is not showing errors but when i run it it's saying result[0].children is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#sortlist").sortable("toArray")` returns an array of sortable items' ids, which is an array of strings.

A string don't have `id` property and `children` method.

Comment: The fiddle throws error `TypeError: result[0].children is not a function
first: { team: result[0].id, value: result[0].children()[0].val() },` which makes me think that there is a metod "id" but there is no "children"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got that code/idea from the answer to this  question of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12443908/jquery-how-do-i-access-this-input-value   If you have time, I'd be grateful if you can explain the appropriate way to get the input value together with the ids of the list items.